# Average program using while loop. Won't calculate correctly

Tags: python, loops, break

```
i = 0
result = 0
while i < 10 :
    result += eval(input("Enter a number: "))
    i += 1
    if result < 1 :
        break
    average = result / i   
print (average)
```

I am making a program to calculated average of 10 numbers but it will terminate if a negative number is entered. The problem is that if a negative number is enter the program won't stop until the negative number is greater than all the other numbers that have been entered.

Comment: So your IF statement (less than 1) is not triggered when you enter a negative value?

Comment: You are mistaken.  Run the program and enter a negative value and you will see it will terminate ( -- and if you haven't yet entered at least 1 value it will also throw an error due to average not being defined yet.)

Comment: Please specify the programming language you're working in by setting the flag. This will make your question visible to the people who work in that language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code doesn't *necessarily* halt on a negative number.  It does this *only* if that negative number brings the *running total* to a non-positive amount.  For example, if the user enters the following numbers:

```
4
-2
4
```

Then the running totals are:

```
4
2
6
```

At no point is the running total (`result`) non-positive.  So the condition for that `break` statement won't be true.

If you want to terminate any time a negative number is entered (or, rather, a non-positive number based on your logic), you need to check that number *itself*, not the running total.  Something like this:

```
i = 0
result = 0
value = 0;
while i < 10 :
    value = eval(input("Enter a number: "))
    if value < 1 :
        break
    i += 1
    result += value
    average = result / i   
print (average)
```

Comment: Good catch, should not be performing calculations right away.